# XML parsing in SQL Server with special character

Tags: string, sql-server-2012, xml-parsing

I am using XML parsing to extract fields from a string in SQL Server. In a normal scenario, it is working fine, but when the string has any kind of special character, it is failing. Looking for a way to get around that. The screenshot is shows an example where it fails:

[image]

Comment: Here is a sample..
123548,jhjl,2018-05-31 14:18:57,2018-05-31 14:22:24,yyyy,String containing ♪ special

Select Special_Char_String.value('/XMLRoot[1]/RowData[6]','varchar(100)')

Comment: Please edit your question adding the data sample with proper formatting